# Need help - Soap service with WS-Security Oasis in .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, ws-security, oasis

I'm trying to create a Service to be consumed from a client.
It must conform the WS-Security Oasis standard and the response must be like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://inti.notariado.org/XML" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351279296">
                        <wsu:Created>2016-02-15T11:18:47.928Z</wsu:Created>
                        <wsu:Expires>2016-02-15T11:23:47.928Z</wsu:Expires>
                    </wsu:Timestamp>
                    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
                                              ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" 
                                              wsu:Id="X509-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351276791">MIIH6zCCB+cw...OMMITED...2lpK
                    </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                    <ds:Signature Id="SIG-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351277955" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                            <ds:Reference URI="#id-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351277904">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                        <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ns" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                </ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>jBhSy8vJGQtkVx9ok+aiLklTMaU=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>ui...OMMITED...eLzGcWA==
                        </ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351277502">
                            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" 
                                                         wsu:Id="STR-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351277533" 
                                                         xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                                                         <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351276791" 
                                                         ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/>
                            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                    </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
    <ns:SERVICE_DISPATCHER>
        <ns:TIMESTAMP>2008-09-29T03:49:45</ns:TIMESTAMP>
        <ns:TIPO_MSJ>1</ns:TIPO_MSJ>
        <ns:EMISOR>TEST</ns:EMISOR>
        <ns:RECEP>CGN</ns:RECEP>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns:SERVICIO>CTREEF</ns:SERVICIO>
        </ns:SERVICE_DISPATCHER>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-3E29AD5728CD9B921B14555351277904" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <ns:SERVICE_DISPATCHER_REQUEST>
        <con:ConsultaTitularidadRealRequest xmlns:con="http://ancert.notariado.org/XML/ConsultaTitularidadReal/Terceros">
            <con:TipoConsulta>EMPRESAS_ACTUAL</con:TipoConsulta>
            <con:TipoResultado>XML_PDF</con:TipoResultado>
            <con:DatosConsulta>
                <con:Identificacion>
                    <con:TipoDocumento>1</con:TipoDocumento>
                    <con:NumeroDocumento>N4361258I</con:NumeroDocumento>
                </con:Identificacion>
            </con:DatosConsulta>            
        </con:ConsultaTitularidadRealRequest>
    </ns:SERVICE_DISPATCHER_REQUEST>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I tried to do it with WSE 3.0 and WCF but I always get stuck and can't find good tutorials about how to secure the service.

So the questions are... What's the best way to develop it? Any good tutorial which could help me? Should I configure security by code or by web.config?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me? I'm still stuck. I just accomplished to send a request and receive the response, but only the body part. How can I add the header part with al these security (signature, timestamp, etc...).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hola. Were you able to get this working? I'm trying to do the same but I'm finding the documentation really incomplete and not enough information out there to piece all the parts together.